# How to start fid at a specific number

Tags: qgis, point, layers

In QGIS Is there a way to change the fid field in my point layer from starting at 1 to start at 101?

Comment: Seems not to make sense... Please provide more information why you think you need that.

Comment: Maybe it is a better solution to append a new column (e.g. "ID") that starts at 10 rather than changing the fid column. The reason being that the fid column is automatically changed, e.g. if you split a polygone, since the fid always needs to be unique.

Comment: I would personal recommend you do not mess around with the FID field as that is maintained by the GIS and if you start joining data on that field you will get yourself in all sorts of problems. As suggested by @Vincé a far safe, more robust approach is to create a new ID field and just leave the FID field to do what it does best.

Comment: What kind of dataset are you using?  QGIS typically shows something like fid_1 when viewing the attribute table of a shapefile and that is not necessarily the same as the intrinsic unique identifier used to order a shapefile's records. (Show using $id in a new field).  Do you just want a field with values you can use for labels, joins, sorts etc. like any other field, or do you want to change the inherent sort order of a shapefile?  If the latter there is no reason to start at 101.  If the former you can use any field and calculator to get unique values using row_number + 100 or $id +101

Comment: Thank you for all the responses. I’m new to QGIS. I will not make any changes to the fid layer and just let it do its thing. Instead, as suggested, I created a separate layer to give each of my points a sequential number starting with 101. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do that, but here we go: In Layer Properties, go to Attributes Form tab and select the `fid` field.

- Set Constraints to `Encofce not null constraint` and `Enforce unique constraint`.
- Set Defaults to `$id+100`

[image]